# Are there better ways to ease this warning?

Tags: c, printf, warnings, bit-fields, gcc-warning

I have a struct where I use bitfields to optimize memory. I have a `uint64_t` type and I want to print its value. When compiled it shows me this warning: `format ‘%lu’ expects argument of type ‘long unsigned int’, but argument 5 has type ‘long unsigned int:48’ [-Wformat=]`

I have already tried to supress this warning by typing while compiling `-Wno-format`. I'm wondering if there are a better way to do it.

Here some code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct gn_addr 
{
    unsigned int m:1;
    unsigned int st:5;
    unsigned int reserved:10;
    uint64_t mid:48;
} gn_addr ;

void gn_addr__print(gn_addr *self)                                                                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    printf("M=>%d\nST=>%d\nReserved=>%d\nMID=>%lu\nTotal size %ld bytes\n",                                                                                                                                
         self->m, self->st, self->reserved, self->mid, sizeof(self));                                                                                                                                   
}
```

Comment: Since you are wildly mixing types and using non-standard bit-field types, the compiler is free to store `m`, `st` and `reserved` in one 32 bit variable and then `mid` in a separate `uint64_t` variable. So your "optimization" can lead to significantly increased memory use, in addition to turning the code completely non-portable. It would have been wiser to drop bit-fields and simply use a single `uint64_t` variable instead.

Comment: Note that `sizeof(self)` is the size of the **pointer** `gn_addr *self` and not the size of the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you should definitely apply the fixes in the other answers to get portable format specifiers, the warning will persist. The reason is that extra arguments to a variadic function like `printf` undergo argument promotions. Argument promotions include integer promotion.

The rules for integer promotions will convert any integer with a conversion rank less than `int`/`unsigned`, as well as bit-fields, into the an `int`/`unsigned`. So for your initial bit-fields, you get `int` automatically.

For integers with a higher conversion rank than `int`/`unsigned`, no promotion occurs. So your bit-field is not promoted to an `uint64_t`, and you get a warning about argument mismatch. You need a cast.

```
(uint64_t)self->mid
```

---

Btw, since nobody mentioned, the portable format specifier for a `size_t` (the type of the `sizeof` operator) is `%zu`. You should use that instead of `%ld`.

Comment: It works perfectly. Thank you by sharing your knowledge!

Comment: In fact C doesn't have built-in standard support for `uint64_t` bit-fields, so what will happen is up to the compiler entirely.

Answer (score 2):

First, use proper format specifier for `uint64_t` and `size_t` types, use `PRIu64` macro, as defined in `inttypes.h` and `%zu`.

That said, for the bit field variables,

- you can either use a cast, like `(uint64_t)self->mid`
- or you can use an intermediate variable of type `uint64_t`, assign the member variable value to the new intermediate variable, and pass that to `printf()` as the corresponding argument to the format specifier, like

  ```
  uint64_t temp = self->mid;
  printf("%"PRIu64 "\n", temp);
  ```

Comment: I'm still getting the same warning. I've also did `printf("%s\n", PRIu64)` and it outputs `lu`

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `printf` are being examined by compilers (not all). The compiler checks if format specifier matches with the type of argument passed. You need to make explicit conversion to make that `Warning` go away. As mentioned in other answers that there are some implicit integer promotion rules and you need to be aware of them (Thanks to @storyTeller).

> The rules for integer promotions will convert any integer with a conversion rank less than  int/unsigned,as well as bit-fields, into the an int/unsigned. So for your initial bit-fields, you get unsigned int automatically.
>
> For integers with a higher conversion rank than int/unsigned, no promotion occurs. So your bit-field is not promoted to an uint64_t, and you get a warning about argument mismatch. You need a cast.

Try this:

```
(uint64_t)self->mid
```

> I have already tried to supress this warning by typing while compiling -Wno-format. I'm wondering if there are a better way to do it.

It's not a good idea to suppress your warnings. They are generated for a reason. I would recommend to use warning flags like `-Wall`, `-Wshadow`, `-Wextra` and other important flags. They can help you with deploying code with lesser number of bugs.

Regarding your assumption:

> I have a struct where I use bitfields to optimize memory.

I would like to point out that your struct with bitfields won't be that much memory optimized as you might be considering it. There is something called `Padding` and `Data Alignment` which may help you further in reducing the memory footprint.

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing).